Buffered Reader hangs for ~8 seconds while checking br.readLine() for the last time
I'm working on some Java 8 code (using Apache httpclient 4.3) to process out the content from an HTTP response. I am able to print out the content but on the last iteration of the while loop after the last line of text has been printed there is about a 15 sec delay before the System.out.println after the loop finally prints.
//PRINT OUT
String line;
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(entityResp.getContent());
            
try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr)){
                
    System.out.println("Before BufferedReader loop");
                
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println(line);
    }
                
    System.out.println("End of stream reached.....");
                    
}
                
//close the InputStreamReader
isr.close();    
System.out.println("After try with resources");
            

This is a sample of the logging output that shows the time gap.
2024-05-02 11:02:25,713 INFO  [stdout] (default task-9) </user>
2024-05-02 11:02:40,707 INFO  [stdout] (default task-9) End of stream reached.....

I have tried processing the BufferedReader char by char and saw the same latency with a \n being the last char there (ASCII 10). I was expecting there to be some sort of end of stream or end of file symbol but upon further reading it seems that getContent() should handle this for transfer-encoding: chunked responses implicitly? The content length of the request is -1 and looking at the spec for this on mozilla that makes sense now. Just a bit confused and any ideas are welcome towards what might be causing this one. The key issue here is that I don't know the content-length so how can I process the chunked data given back to me in the response?

It sounds like BufferedReader is irrelevant to this, really - it's just "the stream returned by getContent() takes a while to report end of content". BufferedReader is just how you happen to be observing that, right? (Reading directly from the stream, you'd see the same thing.)

I'm taking a guess that Apache httpclient is being kind to you and timing out. Otherwise, that read might block 'forever'

You need to parse the content to find the end of the HTTP streaming.

@g00se pardon my ignorance, I'm learning a bit here, why would you expect that to block forever?

Because if the length is not known, you're not going to finish that loop until the end of stream. End of stream might not happen until the connection is closed

@JonSkeet correct, that's just where the symptom shows as I try to process the input stream given by respEntit.getContent() and reach the while loop condition check for the final time after the last bit of xml text is printed out.

Will not happen until the peer closes the connection. @g00se

@user207421, yes that's what I mean

@g00se Big difference between ‘might’ and ‘will’, n’est-ce pas?

Yes, it's better to be precise. Of course to be more precise still it will also happen if the reading peer closes the connection

@g00se No it won’t. That will cause a ‘socket closed’ exception. Stop guessing please.
